# Write double quotes in square brackets to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, escaping

How can I write this into my database field (varchar):

```
["TEXT"]
```

I have tried escaping the quotes with backslashes and using double double quotes.

**Update**
I am using Laravel.

I tried this:

```
$user = User::create(['email'=> $userEmail,
                                        'name'=> $name,
                                        'customer_id'=> $customer->id,
                                        'things'=> '["TEXT"]'
]);
```

and this was the result in the db:
"[\"TEXT\"]"

Comment: Show the PHP code to insert.

Comment: `$var = '["TEXT"]';` ? or use a prepared statement.

Comment: A string is just a string.  How are you *trying* to insert this string into a database?  How is it failing?

Comment: Added some detail to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got I working:

```
  $user = User::create(['email'=> $email,
        'name'=> $name,
        'email'=> $email,
        'customer_id'=> $customer_id,
        'things'=> ["TEXT"]
    ]);
```

Comment: That sets it to an array value of `'TEXT'` without the square brackets. If the square brackets work it's because your field is serialized.

Comment: Where would I be able to see that?

Comment: You need to look at the raw value in the database column, plus examine your User model definition.

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure what do you mean here.. but simply

`INSERT INTO test(varchar_field) VALUES('["TEXT"]');` should help

Comment: Fair enough, but it's a Laravel question now.

Answer (score -1):

That's the correct data. When displaying something with double quotes the inner double quotes will need to be escaped with the backslash character. That is:

```
"[\"TEXT\"]"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
'["TEXT"]'
```

Where no escaping is required because the quotes don't conflict.

This is an artifact of how [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) work.

When you test the insertion you should see the result of:

```
SELECT HEX(things) FROM users WHERE email=?
```

As showing the actual raw hex data for that column which should be:

```
5B2254455854225D
```

Where `5B` represents a `[` and `5D` represents `]`. If you're getting `22` at the front and end then for some reason double quotes are actually getting into your column and not just the way PHP displays strings.

Comment: But, the other records in the db show ["TEXT"] and this new one shows "[\"TEXT\"]".

Comment: You may have double-escaped a single record for some reason. The insertion code you're showing should be working properly but you may have done it differently before.

Comment: What column type is `things`? Is it `TEXT`, `VARCHAR` or `JSON`?

Comment: It is a Varchar.

Comment: Everything in your original code checks out though, so if there's actual quotes inside that field you've got some other problem.